# Stream.toList() does not exist in JDK 17 with Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am using JDK 17 in Android Studio and when I write the code: `collect(Collectors.toList()` Android Studio shows me a warning suggesting that `collect(toList()) can be replaced by toList()`. But when I use the `Stream.toList` method the compiler does not find it. I look for the method in the Stream interface and I can't find it either.

I have tested it in IntelliJ IDEA with the same JDK and it works correctly.

JDK provider: Eclipse Temurin
JDK full version: 17.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Context: Since Java 16 `toList()` has been added to `Collectors`. The older way was using `collect(toList())` when we needed to return a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new List.

My guess is even though you were using JDK 17, in your IDE settings compiler was set below 16. So if you update the compiler settings to 16/17 it can work.

Also, check the dependency file (for example pom.xml in the case of maven) if any dependency has been modified or not. I have never used Android Studio so no idea about the project structure.

Comment: This is not the problem, I am sure I am compiling to JDK 17.